# Creating a Roof function

Tags: revit-api

I'm having trouble to create a roof via code.
I know how to create a stairs for example :
I start a StairsEditScope and use CreateSketchedLanding with all the right parameters to create my stairs and just commit the StairsEditScope, but for a roof i cant find a clue on how to create it from scratch, any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revit provides different kinds of roofs. It is best to understand the various types from an end user point of view before starting to drive them programmatically. The simplest one is defined by a horizontal outline. You can create a roof from such an outline using the Document.NewFootPrintRoof method. Such a roof can be flat, or you can specify a slope for each edge of the outline profile. The Building Coder Xtra labs provide a working sample in the external command Lab2_0_CreateLittleHouse in Labs2.cs:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra/blob/master/XtraCs/Labs2.cs

Here are some other roof-related posts on The Building Coder:

- [RoomsRoofs SDK Sample](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/09/roomsroofs-sdk.html)
- [Roof Eave Cut](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/08/roof-eave-cut-in-revit-and-aca.html)
- [Creating an Extrusion Roof](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/09/events-again-and-creating-an-extrusion-roof.html)