# How to create a roof without creating walls in revit api c#

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am working on a project where I need to create a roof through code in a revit document.
I have gone through the following links:

- https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/help-creating-roof/td-p/5828076
- [Creating a Roof function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718999/creating-a-roof-function)
- http://www.revitapidocs.com/2016/110741bf-b041-9f78-0832-ec9f5892cebc.htm

But all of the above links suggest selecting the walls first.
Can I create a roof without creating the walls?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use the [`NewFootPrintRoof` method](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/110741bf-b041-9f78-0832-ec9f5892cebc.htm) and feed it with a CurveArray to define the footprint.

The external command `Lab2_0_CreateLittleHouse` in [Labs2.cs](https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra/blob/master/XtraCs/Labs2.cs) in the [AdnRevitApiLabsXtra](https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra) sample code demonstrates how:

```
      corners[0] -= w * ( XYZ.BasisX + XYZ.BasisY );
      corners[1] += w * ( XYZ.BasisX - XYZ.BasisY );
      corners[2] += w * ( XYZ.BasisX + XYZ.BasisY );
      corners[3] -= w * ( XYZ.BasisX - XYZ.BasisY );

      CurveArray profile = new CurveArray();

      for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
      {
        Line line = Line.CreateBound( // 2014
          corners[i], corners[3 == i ? 0 : i + 1] );

        profile.Append( line );
      }

      List<Element> roofTypes
        = new List<Element>(
          LabUtils.GetElementsOfType(
            doc, typeof( RoofType ),
            BuiltInCategory.OST_Roofs ) );

      RoofType roofType = roofTypes
        .Cast<RoofType>()
        .FirstOrDefault<RoofType>( typ
          => null != typ.GetCompoundStructure() );

      ModelCurveArray modelCurves
        = new ModelCurveArray();

      FootPrintRoof roof
        = createDoc.NewFootPrintRoof( profile,
          levelTop, roofType, out modelCurves );
```